# How to reload Store every X seconds?

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 4 MVC.

Is there a way to reload Store every X seconds?

I'd like to put code somewhere to `Controller`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Use Ext.getStore to reference your store from the controller
    var myStore = Ext.getStore('YourStore');
    // Pass in an object of the changes you want to be made to the store
    myStore.proxy.extraParams = { key:'sencha'}; // replace with your own object
    myStore.load();

},3000);
```

Comment: extraParams are for params that get submited with each request. To apply param for a specific load operation they should be applied  calling `load({params:{key:'sencha'}})`. It is a bad design to change the extraParams each time.

Answer (score 1):

FYI in Extjs this is possible to implement via [Ext.util.TaskRunner](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner).
A sample code:

```
var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner(),
clock, updateClock, task;

clock = Ext.getBody().appendChild({
    id: 'clock'
});

// Start a simple clock task that updates a div once per second
updateClock = function() {
    clock.setHtml(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'g:i:s A'));
};

task = runner.start({
    run: updateClock,
    interval: 1000
});
```